# Implement Azure AD Authorization in DRF backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, azure-active-directory

I'm creating an Angular app with a Django Rest Framework backend. I have followed [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-enable-azure-ad-authentication-in-angular-and-web-api-core-app/) tutorial for implementing Azure Active Directory in the Angular app. That part works but I dont' know how to implement the Azure AD in the backend. Form the tutorial it looks like I have the set the token in de header and the backend checks with the AD of the token correct is. How do I do that in DRF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here are few python github samples that might help you, [ms-identity-python-webapp](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp) and 
[app-service-web-python-get-started](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-get-started). Could you please take a look at it and let us know?